# Audio & Video of Local Computer to a RDC PC

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, slack, google-meet

I have my Laptop A in City Toronto that I would like to Remote Desktop Connection into PC B in City Vancouver.

I would like to use my Laptop A video & audio for PC B for meetings in Google Meet & Slack etc through Remote Desktop.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why the hell aren't you using the meeting clients directly on laptop A? This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Let's just say that my location has to come from PC B - so I would log in to my accounts in B and connect to it from A to make it look like I am working at B but in reality I would be in city A.

Comment: There is no remote client software (as far as I know) that does what you want. And how is the other party on the other end of the meeting to know from where the call is coming? In most video-conferencing tools you can't tell where the other party is located anyway. I routinely participate in Teams meetings from 2 different laptops, an iPhone and an iPad. And from 3 different countries. Unless I tell the other side from where I calling and on which device they have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Remote Desktop is a one-way street. If you remote into B from A, you can use the mic & video from B on A but not the other way round. [It would also be as slow as all heck, RDP is not optimised for 'Zoom-like' interaction.]

Comment: Yeah, that is fine. As long as I can use Google Meet/Hangout and talk from my laptop A and make it look like it is coming from B for the person I am meeting with. Will that work?

Comment: No. You can use the mic & video from the one you're NOT sitting at. Not the other way round.